# Where is the site.master in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express - MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer, master-pages

Okay, this is probably a very newbie question, but how can I get to site.master??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the default ASP.NET MVC project template this file should be located in :

```
~/Views/Shared/Site.master
```